# ST_SnapToGrid and ST_Union resulting in slivers

Tags: qgis, sql, merge, slivers

I am currently trying to merge polygons (streets and pavements) into one, the resulting merged polygon has slivers (Image 1).

Changing the tolerance (0.1) has an effect on this but results in slivers elsewhere in the data, and when manually merged (in QGIS) I am getting some outlier points as can been seen in image 2.

I am using this workflow for a large dataset that will be updated regularly so manually going in and fixing the problems won't be a way of solving this.

Has anyone had any similar problems?

Example code can be seen below.

Merge using sql (Image 1):

[image]

Manualy merged in QGIS (Image 2):

[image]

```
--Drop and create Type 1/2 adopted layer
    
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS highway_network.t12_adopted_network;
    CREATE TABLE highway_network.t12_adopted_network AS
    SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(wkb_geometry,0.01)) as wkb_geometry, t12_usrn as usrn, t12_desc as street 
    FROM highway_network.highway_adopted_final
    GROUP BY t12_usrn, t12_desc;

-- Add a serial column and make it a primary key
    ALTER TABLE highway_network.t12_adopted_network  ADD COLUMN ogc_fid serial NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE highway_network.t12_adopted_network  ADD CONSTRAINT t12_adopted_network_pk PRIMARY KEY (ogc_fid);

--Drop and create Type 1/2 adopted layer components
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS highway_network.t12_adopted_network_component;
    CREATE TABLE highway_network.t12_adopted_network_component AS
    SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(wkb_geometry,0.01)) as wkb_geometry, t12_usrn as usrn, t12_desc as street, usage_code as component 
    FROM highway_network.highway_adopted_final
    GROUP BY t12_usrn, t12_desc, usage_code;

-- Add a serial column and make it a primary key
    ALTER TABLE highway_network.t12_adopted_network_component ADD COLUMN ogc_fid serial NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE highway_network.t12_adopted_network_component ADD CONSTRAINT t12_adopted_network_component_pk PRIMARY KEY (ogc_fid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved - v.clean and rmarea in GRASS solved this problem